# Is it safe, if i use session_id() for session key?

Tags: php

I want to ask the login system technique, here my login system script, is it safe if i use session_id() for my session key. and shall you all share your login system to me for more references. Thank you.

```
<?php
class Login {
    function __construct(){

    }

    function is_logged_in(){
        if(empty($_SESSION)){
            session_start();
        }

        if(empty($_SESSION[session_id()])){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    function get_user(){
        if(!$this->is_logged_in()){
            return $this->login();
            exit();
        }

        return $_SESSION;
    }

    function set_user($userattr){
        $_SESSION[session_id()] = $userattr;
    }

    function login(){
        if(isset($_POST['btnlogin'])){
            $config = new Config;
            $result = "";
            $sql = $config->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM auth
                                          WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'
                                          AND passcode = '".md5($_POST['password'])."'");
            $sql->execute();
            if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
                $this->set_user(array('username' => 
                                    $_POST['username'])
                                );
                header("Location: ./index.php");
            }else{
                echo 'wrong username or pass';  
            }
        }
        ?>
        <div id="login-box">
            <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="text" name="username" class="input-field" required="true" placeholder="type your username" />
                <input type="password" name="password" class="input-field" required="true" placeholder="type your password" />
                <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="login-button" name="btnlogin" /> 
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: your login-code is extremely unsafe. you are wide open to **SQL injections**, just imagine someone posting the username `' DROP TABLE auth; --`. you already are using prepared statements, so *why* don't you use parameters? also: `md5` has been insecure **for years now**. use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, okay i'll to searching about password_hash and password_verify, now, how about session_id i used for my session?

Comment: i think it's superfluous, since the used session *is* defined by the session-ID itself. it's just redundant.

Comment: Thanks @FranzGleichmann, oke, I'll use a key from generate char for my session. I think it will better.

Comment: Note that the session is ***per user*** so there is no need for a different / random name, you could just use `$_SESSION['username']`.

Comment: @jeroen, use $_SESSION['username'], just imagine, the username is "adam" and "adam" in the table there are more username with "adam".

Comment: @MuhFadlySangadji The session doesn't have anything to do with the table, the whole session is ***unique per user / visitor***. Nevertheless usernames definitely should be unique by themselves...

Comment: I see. thanks for the clue.

Comment: How about i used a key from generate char for my session key? Is it redundant? Ex : $_SESSION[$generatedkey], cz i usualy see many tutorials expln like that.